# Is there a way to be able to connect to 3g or 4g network with my laptop while on the road without going through a cell phone company?

Tags: 3g

I would like to use my laptop while on the road to connect to the web for homeschool purposes for my son.  My kindle has 3g and I do not want to have to take out a subscription with ATT or Verizon to be able to use the laptop while away from my wifi at home.  Is that possible?

Comment: You have to pay someone for access to their 3g/4g network. Nobody is going to give it to you for free.

Comment: 3g and 4g are **mobile** protocols, so yes you would need to pay someone. Unless your kindle had wi-fi, in this case you could access wherever a free access point existed.

Comment: Shows what y'all know -- some Kindles have permanent free 3G service out of the box; they cost a little more to buy than otherwise equivalent non-3G versions, but there's no monthly fee. Of course, since somebody figured out how to jailbreak and tether them, there's also a 50MB monthly data cap, so it wouldn't be of much use to the asker anyway; even if it were, all the problems of illicit tethering still apply, namely the provider detecting the excess usage and terminating the service for T&C violation.

Comment: @AaronMiller There is a monthly fee. Amazon pays it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Amazon does, sure. The end user, in your earlier comment cited as "you", doesn't, which I guess in the context of said comment makes Amazon "nobody". More seriously, such unworthy quibbles embarrass all involved.

Comment: @AaronMiller The end user pays Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but highly technical and not without risk of bricking your Kindle in the process, and not long after somebody figured out how to do it in the first place, Amazon applied a 50MB/month data cap to Kindle 3G service -- so even if you did jailbreak your Kindle and set up tethering, it still wouldn't be any real use. Your best option is probably to find a relatively inexpensive cellular plan that includes data and tethering.